# split string into many columns with value in the same string Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pivot, strip

Starting from the column "code", I need (by Python code) to pivot columns with the name of each string that contain the associated number (see example below)

| id | code | C | HD | HT | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 74C + 24HD | 74 | 24 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 23C + 14HT + 3S | 23 | 0 | 14 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your initial dataframe `df` looks like

```
   id             code
0   1       74C + 24HD
1   2  23C + 14HT + 3S
2   3                0
3   4    0.40C + 32.3P
```

If that's the case then you could try to use [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) in combination with [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html): Use a pattern that matches the number-columnname-combinations and groups both parts. `.extractall` then extracts the parts into separate columns. The column that contains the column name part can then be pulled into columns with `.pivot`.

```py
new_cols_df = (
    df["code"].str.extractall(r"(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?P<column>[A-Z]+)").droplevel(1)
    .pivot(columns="column")
    .droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
df = pd.concat([df, new_cols_df], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

to get

```
   id             code     C  HD  HT     P  S
0   1       74C + 24HD    74  24   0     0  0
1   2  23C + 14HT + 3S    23   0  14     0  3
2   3                0     0   0   0     0  0
3   4    0.40C + 32.3P  0.40   0   0  32.3  0
```

In case you need numeric values in the new columns:

```py
df[df.columns[2:]] = df[df.columns[2:]].astype("float")
```

Comment: This code return ValueError: "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jresearcher Looks like the index of `df` has duplicates? I have added 2 lines that might help with that.

Comment: @Jresearcher Additional question: Is `id` the index of `df`, and not a column?

Comment: my df has no duplicates on the index. However, even using the reset_index it doesn't seem to work, it gives me the same error.
Id is not the index of my df. I have Python Index and also the column id. Each row is for me an indipendent entity.

Comment: @Jresearcher Ok, then I suspect that `code` could have items which contain columns multiple times, like e.g. `23C + 14HT + 3C` (the `C` is in there twice): Could that be?

Comment: I've checked my dataset and yes, some sort of contains might happen. Example: I could have 3C + 4CP + 5P (C is is in C e CP, but is not the same thing).

Comment: @Jresearcher Hm, that shouldn't break anything? (I've tried it in the sample.)

Comment: I can't figure out why this happens. I'm trying to look for errors in the data.
When u say "# In case the index has duplicates" are you referring to the python index or id?

Comment: @Jresearcher I mean `df.index`.

Comment: OK! Understood. I have things like "72C + 12C[p]". This seems to cause problems. I replaced C[p] with CP and now it seems to work!!! A thousand thanks!

Comment: Just another question. If have I to manage and include decimals, how can I do? Ex. 0.40C + 32.3P

Comment: @Jresearcher I've updated the answer to cover that too. But be aware that it might not work properly when the float numbers have a different format.

Comment: It actually doesn't work.. I don't know why but it expands the value on the other columns.

Comment: @Jresearcher Could there be a format that is different from the example in the answer, eg. could the float look like `.5P`, ie. without a leading number before the decimal point?

Comment: No, i haven't similar case. Now it works, maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str.extract` here along with `np.where`:

```py
df["C"] = np.where(~df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)C\b').isnull(), df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)C\b').astype(int), 0)
df["HD"] = np.where(~df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)HD\b').isnull(), df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)HD\b').astype(int), 0)
df["HT"] = np.where(~df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)HT\b').isnull(), df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)HT\b').astype(int), 0)
df["S"] = np.where(~df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)S\b').isnull(), df["code"].str.extract(r'\b(\d+)S\b').astype(int), 0)
```

Comment: This solution may be too hard tailed. I don't know if another code arrives tomorrow (example 4PH) that would not be managed.

Comment: If the number of output columns be variable, then you would need a much larger dynamic script to do the extraction.

Comment: Can u help me about this?

Comment: I am a Pandas beginner, and the above answer is the best I can do.